# Update tables row from XML datatype in Sql server

Tags: sql-server, xml

I m not so good to use Xml data type in Sql,
I have one table Named RSN_ALL, 
and  i need to insert data to that table from my One Xml File.. for that I create One Store Procedure.

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[SPInsertXmlData]
 (
@xmlData XML
 )
as
 begin

  insert into RSN_All 
 (
Batch_M_id,
RSN,
Parent_RSN,
Pkg_Location,
CompanyId   
)

SELECT
COALESCE
([Table].[Column].value('Batch_M_id[1]', 'bigint'),0) as 'Batch_M_id',
[Table].[Column].value('RSN [1]', 'varchar(20)') as ' RSN ',
[Table].[Column].value(' Parent_RSN[1]', 'varchar(20)') as ' Parent_RSN',
[Table].[Column].value(' Pkg_Location [1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as ' Pkg_Location',
[Table].[Column].value(' CompanyId [1]', 'int') as ' CompanyId'

 FROM @xmlData.nodes('/ NewDataSet / Table') as [Table]([Column])


 IF(@@ROWCOUNT > 0 )
 select   'SUCCESS' as msg

  end
```

and it works Perfectly ,

but i need Some Modification i want  to check if this row its already Present Than update that row other wise insert row. (RSN column is my Unique Column),

I am not getting how to do this, please help me

As per @Hoots reply This is My new Store procedure

```
   ALTER procedure [dbo].[SPInsertXmlData]
   (
   @xmlData XML
   )
   as
    begin 

   -- import xml into temp table
    SELECT
    COALESCE
   ([Table].[Column].value('Batch_M_id[1]', 'bigint'),0) as 'Batch_M_id',
   [Table].[Column].value('RSN [1]', 'varchar(20)') as ' RSN ',
  [Table].[Column].value(' Parent_RSN[1]', 'varchar(20)') as ' Parent_RSN',
  [Table].[Column].value(' Pkg_Location [1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as ' Pkg_Location',
  [Table].[Column].value(' CompanyId [1]', 'int') as ' CompanyId'
   into #temp_xml
    FROM @xmlData.nodes('/ NewDataSet / Table') as [Table]([Column])


 BEGIN TRY
    -- start the transaction
   BEGIN TRANSACTION

-- now do the updates
update ra
set 
ra.Batch_M_id =tx. Batch_M_id,
ra.RSN=tx.RSN , 
ra.Parent_RSN =tx.Parent_RSN,
ra.Pkg_Location=tx.Pkg_Location,
ra.CompanyId= tx.CompanyId

from RSN_ALL ra
inner join #temp_xml tx on (tx.RSN = ra.RSN ) -- the fields that identify existence
select 'Ok' as msg

-- now do the inserts
insert into RSN_All (Batch_M_id,RSN,Parent_RSN,Pkg_Location,CompanyId)
 select * 
from #temp_xml tx
where not exists (select 1 from RSN_All ra where tx.RSN= ra.RSN) -- the same fields that identify existence

-- commit the transaction
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
-- Any problems rollback transaction
IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
END
END CATCH;

-- drop temp table
 drop table #temp_xml
 end
```

But still its not working ..
Its show Error Invalid Column name 'RSN', This is My XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
   <Batch_M_id>10</Batch_M_id>
   <RSN>01HE55WV</RSN>
   <Parent_RSN />
   <Pkg_Location>1  </Pkg_Location>
   <CompanyId>21</CompanyId>
 </Table>
 <Table>
  <Batch_M_id>10</Batch_M_id>
  <RSN>01DK7KNH</RSN>
  <Parent_RSN />
  <Pkg_Location>1  </Pkg_Location>
  <CompanyId>21</CompanyId>
 </Table> 
</NewDataSet>
```

Parent_RSN tag its NuLl may be it Creates Problem, So Give Some Value but Still Is Showing Same Error Invalid Column Name RSN

Comment: You've got spaces in your column names in the coalesce statement. I would think removing the spaces should do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do an insert and an update in a single sql statement, you will need to use one for each the update and insert, infact I would probably import the xml data into a temporary table first and then do your manipulation...

```
-- import xml into temp table
select COALESCE([Table].[Column].value('Batch_M_id[1]', 'bigint'),0) as 'Batch_M_id',
            [Table].[Column].value('RSN [1]', 'varchar(20)') as ' RSN ',
            [Table].[Column].value(' Parent_RSN[1]', 'varchar(20)') as ' Parent_RSN',
            [Table].[Column].value(' Pkg_Location [1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as ' Pkg_Location',
            [Table].[Column].value(' CompanyId [1]', 'int') as ' CompanyId'
into #temp_xml
FROM @xmlData.nodes('/ NewDataSet / Table') as [Table]([Column])

BEGIN TRY
    -- start the transaction
    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    -- now do the updates
    update ra ...
    set ....
    from RSN_ALL ra
    inner join #temp_xml tx on (tx... = ra...) -- the fields that identify existence

    -- now do the inserts
    insert into RSN_All (Batch_M_id,RSN,Parent_RSN,Pkg_Location,CompanyId)
    from #temp_xml tx
    where not exists (select 1 from RSN_All ra where tx... = ra...) -- the same fields that identify existence

    -- commit the transaction
    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    -- Any problems rollback transaction
    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
    END
END CATCH;

-- drop temp table
drop table #temp_xml
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response.. let me try this first and then i will reply u back

Comment: Its Works Perfectly By Applying Some minor Modification.. Thank you Very Much.. I also mention here my Updated Procedure

Answer (score 0):

as Per @HOOT Suggest Me I Create Below Procedure And Its Work Perfectly

```
CREATE procedure [dbo].[SPInsertXmlData]
 (
  @xmlData XML
   )
 as
  begin 


 -- import xml into temp table
SELECT
COALESCE
([Table].[Column].value('Batch_M_id[1]', 'bigint'),0) as Batch_M_id,
[Table].[Column].value('RSN [1]', 'varchar(20)') as RSN,
[Table].[Column].value(' Parent_RSN[1]', 'varchar(20)') as Parent_RSN,
[Table].[Column].value(' Pkg_Location [1]', 'nvarchar(100)') as Pkg_Location,
[Table].[Column].value(' CompanyId [1]', 'int') as CompanyId
into #temp_xml
FROM @xmlData.nodes('/ NewDataSet / Table') as [Table]([Column])


BEGIN TRY
 -- start the transaction
BEGIN TRANSACTION

---- now do the updates
update ra
set 
  ra.Batch_M_id =tx.Batch_M_id,
 ra.Parent_RSN =tx.Parent_RSN,
ra.Pkg_Location=tx.Pkg_Location,
ra.CompanyId= tx.CompanyId

from RSN_ALL ra
inner join #temp_xml tx on (ra.RSN =tx.RSN   ) -- the fields that identify existence

-- now do the inserts (Batch_M_id,RSN,Parent_RSN,Pkg_Location,CompanyId)
insert into RSN_All 
select *   
from #temp_xml tx
where not exists (select 1 from RSN_All ra where tx.RSN= ra.RSN) -- the same fields that identify existence

-- commit the transaction
COMMIT TRANSACTION
 END TRY
  BEGIN CATCH
   -- Any problems rollback transaction
   IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0
  BEGIN
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
 END
 END CATCH;

  -- drop temp table
  drop table #temp_xml


 end
```

Comment: @Hoots Sorry I mark first your answer than mine, i do not know here only one answer accepted .